# Need Help Converting DateTime Using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have the follow code, but having trouble removing the Z at the end. The time format looks like this `2020-07-28T15:47:36.165310258Z`

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(f[a]['Created On'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

When using the %f, I noticed that it is only able to the next 6 digit. Is there any way to make it take more? This is the error that I am getting `(MISSING) ValueError: unconverted data remains: 258Z`

What is the best way to remove the Z and have it just return the date?

Comment: `strptime` isn't great for dealing with ISO8601 formatted strings. I'd suggest using [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get around the issue by just moving the last 4 characters from the string and then using datetime.strptime on it.

datetime.strptime(f[a]['Created On'][:-4], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")